# Codename one :Fingerprint scanner doesnt work properly

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented finger print scanner functinality in codename one with below code

```
  int fingerPrintCounter=0;

    @Override
protected void postFinerPrint(Form f) {

    while(fingerPrintCounter<3){
            fingerPrintCounter++;
    fingerPrintScanner();       //finger print scanner method
    }
    if(!fingerPrintStatus)
    {
       showForm("Login", null);
    }
  }

private void fingerPrintScanner() {

    if (!Fingerprint.isAvailable()) {
        fingerPrintCounter=3;       
        showForm("Login", null);

    } else {
        Fingerprint.scanFingerprint("Use your finger print", value -> {
            fingerPrintCounter=3;
            showForm("Home",null)
        }, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
            if (Dialog.show("SCAN FAILED", "Please try again", "OK", null)) {   
                fingerPrintStatus=false;                    
            }

        }, false);

    }
}
```

It's not working properly.I want to scan finger print on form open.On successfull finger print scan "Home" form should open and on failed it should scan finger print again three times untill successfull scan and after successive three failed scans it should go to "Login" form for asking credential.
In my case it working differently on different devices.On older android OS it's working partially.
On latest android OS failed message comes three time before finger print scan.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the failed message?

Comment: I have mentioned in above code .It directly goes to failed condition without scanning fingerprint and Shows the message"Scan Failed,Please try again" which I displaying in failed state of above function.

Comment: "OS failed message" is what I'm referring to

Comment: What is the solution???

Comment: I still don't understand the problem because I have no idea what "native OS dialog" you are referring to